# Getting absolute positioned item over a relative one. (IE)

Tags: css

Please refer to [test site](http://louiswalch.com/beta/css_absoulte_relative.html). Having problems in IE (6&7) getting an absolute positioned item to appear OVER one that is relatively positioned.

The yellow box (absolute) should appear over the blue box (relative). I tried giving the blue one a z-index lower then yellow, but this did not appear to work.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the z-index on the orange box, since that's the one containing the yellow box. In IE6/7 the yellow box will only have a higher z-index than other elements inside the orange container.

```
#orange {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: orange;
}
#blue {
   background-color:blue;
   height:100px;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
   width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify z-index for the blue box explicitly:

```
#yellow {
background-color: yellow;
width: 100px;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 200;
}

#blue {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Even better, specify z-index for all three boxes to eliminate any misinterpretation by browsers.